# How to tell what the net amount in a payment from an employer should be?

Tags: canada, payment, employment

I had parted ways from a former employer. I had worked full time and my pay rate was always the same. There were some complicating factors and the timing and amount of the last few payments were different from the rest. My question is, how does one actually calculate what the net pay should be? It seems like lots of deductions are variable.

My pay stubs are very cryptic and full of abbreviations and acronyms.The employer was large and disorganized and asking for explanations on things like this has largely been unproductive. Must an employer explain in clear and full terms a pay stub and all the deductions?

A few of the things my pay stubs included: gross pay, income tax, CPP, EI, taxable benefits, deductions and net pay.

On my last pay stub the income tax was very much more than the rest. Why is this? Also CPP and EI seemed to fluctuate around a certain amount. Why is this? Deductions seems to refer to pension payments, which I never was told how much would be going into it. Given these "variables" how do I actually know how much I should get getting paid?

How can I tell how much I should receive for unused vacation time? On the pay tubs they all say "leave bank: Vac 3.12 hours". I was never told if the vacation time accrued or was a lump sum.

Comment: If it makes a difference, this is in the province BC.